# Нахождение ближайшего адреса(номер дома) относительно точки

Tags: android, яндекс-карты, карты, yandexmapkit

Использую yandex map kit 3.0.

Подскажите, как получить ближайший адрес относительно точки.

Например, указал точку на дороге, а мне бы выдало ближайший дом к этой точке.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать поиск, например, так:

```
    SearchManager searchManager = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createSearchManager(SearchManagerType.ONLINE);
    Session searchSession = searchManager.submit(
            new Point(55.733846, 37.588198),
            14,
            new SearchOptions().setSearchTypes(SearchType.GEO.value),
            new Session.SearchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSearchResponse(Response response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchError(Error error) {

                }
            });
```

Или просто искать в небольшой окрестности нужной точки.